# json php 5.3.23 centos 5 json

Tags: php, json, centos

I have been having an issue trying to install and configure json.

The error i have now is >

```
# PHP warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so: undefined symbol:ZVAL_DELREF in unknown on line 0 -bash: PHP: command not found
#PHP depracated: Directive safe mode is depracated in PHP 5.3 and greater in unknown on line 0
```

I followed these instructions -

1. Download the json package

   `# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/json-1.2.0.tgz`
2. Untar and goto the newly created directory

   `# tar -zxf json-1.2.0.tgz`
   `# cd json-1.2.0`
3. Create the configuration files and configure json

   `# phpize` 
   `# ./configure`
4. Create the installation file and install it

   `# make` 
   `# make install`

Once done, json.so will be created in `/usr/lib64/php/modules/` directory and needs to be called by the php configuration directory

```
# cd /etc/php.d 
# echo “extension=json.so” >> json.ini
```

Everything seemed to work fine, but now im going round in circles. Can anyone suggest where I should start looking or researching to correct this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you getting error for using json_encode or json_decode functions ? if they working properly. Then you can completely ignore to install pecl json. As json is integrated part of php 5.3 core. You no need to install it. See [php json](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.requirements.php) Start up error can be ignored in this case.